# Update field data added in user form using a hook?

Tags: forms, users

I've added three fields in user form.

1. User code
2. User name
3. User ID.

I want to add this field data into the database. My question is, in which hook, i should write the logic of manipulating and saving data.

Comment: How did you add fields to user form? If you used admin interface (admin/config/people/accounts/fields) all information will be automatically stored in the database

Comment: Ya. absolutely correct. But it can be done by new user at time of registration. What i want is, Those accounts which is already their since long, I want to update that one.

Comment: I found solution using user_import module. It worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Hook implementation depends on ***when*** you want to manipulate the user account data.

- Before creation of a new user account, [`hook_user_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7).
- Before updating any user account, [`hook_user_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7).

If you need to update existing users with new data you need your own custom function that makes user of [`user_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7) (to load a user object) & [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) (to save your manipulated user object with new data).